# MySQL - Set maximum number of result sets per query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, multiple-resultsets

When running a large stored procedure mysql script, I am getting the following error
`The maximum number of result sets per query is reached (100).`

After looking around I have found a few articles that say I can change that limit specifically in mysql workbench, but I am looking for a config option for my my.ini file to apply it across the entire server I am running.

It would be awesome to simply do something like
`max_result_set=5000` or something.

Thanks for all help, in advance.

Comment: I don't think this is a MySQL server setting.  I think this is specific to the MySQL Workbench client. (One test would be to run the stored procedure from a different client, like the MySQL command line client.)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it on Workbench after I had gotten the issue on the PHPStorm Database client. Thinking maybe it was a client issue... Maybe I got unlucky and tried it on two clients that both had bad settings? I'll look into the client settings. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know for sure there isn't some system variable in MySQL Server that influences the settings in the clients. I'm just not aware of any server setting that specifically limits the number of resultsets to a particular integer value, ... more likely we'd be bounded by memory, execution time, or other resource limits.

Comment: Yeah it makes way more sense that it would be a setting in the config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to Spencer for the thought to check the client settings! (duh!)

[image]

There was a setting burried deep in the `Advanced` tab of the `Data Sources and Drivers` configuration box. Just for anyone also using that Jetbrain `Database Tools and SQL` plugin (https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)